# Why PowerMock runs private method when I call verifyPrivate?

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock

I'm testing some methodA which has another one inside and I need to check that that methodB has not been called due to return.
If I run this test with debug, everything works correctly. But test fails as PowerMock runs it somewhere underhood.

My test:

```
@Test
public void incomingCall_dismissIncoming_incomingDataNull() throws Exception {
    mIncomingCallData = null;
    Whitebox.setInternalState(SUT, "mLastIncomingCallData", mIncomingCallData);

    SUT.dismissIncoming();

    verifyPrivate(SUT, times(0)).invoke("onIncomingCallDeclined");
}
```

**The question is why is that and how can I test it?** I know I don't need to test private methods, but I need it in this specific case.